# bundled JRE getting corrupted after maven build

Tags: java, maven

I have bundled `JRE` with my project. In the batch file that launches my application, I have set `path` variable to point to bundled `JRE`.

The problem is when I do maven build for my project, and try to launch the application in target folder, application fails to launch because the bundled `JRE` is getting corrupted after maven build.

Is there any solution for this, like skipping build fot `JRE` folder.

My folder structure is D:\Code\Resources\config and `JRE` folder is inside the same folder.

Comment: How does your project structure looks? Without any code we cannot help you.

Comment: Folder structure for project is below:   D:\Code\Resources\config and JRE folder is inside it.

Comment: Don't use the comments to add information to your question, [edit] the question instead

Comment: I have added folder structures. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you also show your pom.xml mainly the `<build>` section is important

Comment: Add the relevant section of the build config and the errors you're finding when your program tries to use the alledgely-corrupted JRE.

Comment: I am getting the error as 'The application was unable to start correctly (0x000005)'.

Comment: If you're defining the JRE directory as a resource in your Maven build, be sure you do not activate filtering, so that you do not corrupt binary files.

Comment: I am not specifying JRE folder in my POM.xml file. I have just added the folder in my project and made changes in batch file to point it while executing.